# Login fail with no error

Tags: login

For no apparent reason since this morning I cannot not log in my Wordpress website https://www.taoperf.com

Yesterday it worked fine - since that time, no updates performed and no activity through wp-admin

Symptoms: I select the login menu option, enter username and password... it returns to the home screen with in the address bar "?wppb_cpm_redirect=yes" and I am not logged in.

the login page is tao_login581 (I guess this has been set by AIO WP Security)

What I have tried (cache cleared between each test):

- enabled error logging in wp-config.php = no error reported during any of the tests
- login with a different username / pwd = same outcome
- changed password in database = same outcome
- login with wrong password = error message (normal!)
- disabled all plugins through database - going to wp-admin redirects to wp-login - enter credentials = keeps coming back to wp-login screen
- reset .htaccess to default = no impact on problem
- restored yesterday's database backup = no impact
- reinstalled Wordpress in new directory and copied over wp-config.php + wp-content = no impact
- changed theme to twentytwentyone + disabled all plugin (through database) and try to login wp-admin = keeps coming back to login screen

The site is hosted on a VPS on which I have full control.  All looks OK: low usage of resources, no exception messages

Anyone with an idea about something I can try?
Thank you for any input

Comment: wppb_cpm_redirect Seems to be from the Profile Builder plugin. Are you using that? What if you delete the plugin entirely? Do you have anything in wp-content/mu-plugins? Those can’t be deactivated from the database.

Comment: Yes Jacob, I use the Profile Builder plugin with a few of its extensions.  There is no wp-content/mu-plugins directory.

Comment: Random question, but are you using LiquidWeb for hosting?  If you are, that was an issue across a number of their WordPress hosting servers.  I believe it's fixed now.

Comment: No, my hosting is with Contabo and it is a VPS where I have full control on the environment.  All seems to be OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a plugin did update ( if they are set to be auto-updated ), then this plugin may have crushed the dashboard.

so you can try to test "[manually disable plugins Wordpress](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wordpress-plugins/)"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried to do it with FTP (rename plugins folder) and phpMyAdmin.  But no effect

Comment: Yes Ahmad, I tend to agree with you regarding the auto-update and I did not restore plugins from previous backup.  I do have some plugins set to auto-update, but I (should?) know about it as  UpdraftPlus makes an automatic backup before the update I get the result by email. 
Maybe UpdraftPlus missed a backup so I did not know?

Comment: That was probably the cause for the problem.  I found out that Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP) was set to auto-update and did an update that night... but apparently UpdraftPlus Premium did not do a backup! I have now disabled all auto-update.

Answer (score 0):

For no apparent reason, this morning I can login again!!!

A pity I cannot reproduce, but at least the 8 hours I spent looking for the answer were not completely wasted as I now know a bit more about the workings of Wordpress.
Thank you for the contributions